# is it needed to implement POST PUT DELETE when consuming an api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I developed an API and managed to consume the API too. As I understood i thought that consuming an API means just implementing the GET method but still not sure whether i also need to implement POST DELETE & PUT. I googled everywhere on this but was not able to find a proper article that discussed on it therefore, can someone please help me get an understanding or at least direct me on to a proper article that discusses on it. many thanks.

Comment: We don't know what your services do, so how could we possibly know whether you need to use POST, DELETE or PUT? Please read [ask]

Comment: I guess it simple if you dont understand why you would need the POST PUT DELETE, then you don't need them

Comment: I suspect that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what *consuming* an API means. It is just another term for *using* an API. You can only consume/use the methods that the API provides. If you implement additional methods for the API, that has nothing to do with *consuming* the API.

Comment: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE have different purposes. Google for "HTTP verbs" to find a good tutorial that helps you to understand.

Comment: @GrantWinney i used the all the four CRUD operations when running the api via FIDDLER now i developed a web form to consume the api.  and  added the GET on to it. not well sue if  need to implement the  POST DELETE PUT also to it

Comment: Consuming an API means making use of its methods in a client application. If you have POST, PUT, and DELETE methods on your API, how do you hope to use them from the client if you don't implement them? Either your question is poorly worded or... or... I don't know. I'm at a bit of a loss for words I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what actions are you providing in your API for your resources.

If your API only reads data, it is okay to have all with GET request, because the HTTP protocol says that GET should be used for retrieving data:

> The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.

But for example, if your API allows the creation of a new resource, you need a POST request for such actions:

> The POST method is used to submit an entity to the specified resource, often causing a change in state or side effects on the server

If you want to learn more about HTTP methods, you can head to [HTTP Requests Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) article in mozilla.org

Of course, when consuming your API, it depends on what you want to accomplish. If you want to create a new resource, you'll need to make a POST request, if you want to destroy a resource, you'll need to make a DESTROY request, and so on.

Comment: i used the all the four CRUD operations when running the api via FIDDLER now i developed a web form to consume the api. and added the GET on to it. not well sue if need to implement the POST DELETE PUT also to it

Comment: That's why it depends. Your form will be used for a specific action. For example, if you're using the form for creating a new resource, you have to put `method="POST"` HTML Tag on it. If your form will destroy a resource, you have to put `method="DELETE"`, and so on.

Comment: can the downvoter explain the reason? :|

Comment: @muZk: I didn't downvote, but it's a frequently observed pattern, that answers on bad questions are downvoted too, regardles of their quality.

Comment: @muZk whats wrong with the question it was purely a lack of understanding